# How to remove 'spaces' using StringChangeEx in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to remove ALL SPACES from a string in Inno Setup, here is the code:

```pascal
S := '4 0 : 8 D : 5 C';
StringChangeEx(S, ' ', '<q>', True);
```

I want the output as **40:8D:5C**
It's not working, where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What did you mean by the `<q>`?

Comment: Sorry for late response, was not around, the <q> doesn't really mean anything, I can use 'any_character ' instead of that, :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The q tag doesn't seem to work in Inno Setup, but this works just fine..

```pascal
S := '4 0 : 8 D : 5 C';
StringChangeEx(S, ' ', '', True);
```